# Comments system doesn't like International domains

Tags: comments

Morning all,

I'm trying to work out why the commenting system thinks .au, .ca and a couple of other international email address are being treating as invalid.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress’ internal email validation is very weak. I’ve written a plugin some time ago to catch *most* cases where WordPress fails: [Extend Email Checks](https://gist.github.com/972837).

It uses PHP’s [`filter_var()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php). But there are some edge cases, where it doesn’t work good enough. Give it a try.

Comment: looks good, I've deployed it where needed. Will see if it resolves issues.